# How to pause but not freeze Android execution?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set the background color of an ImageView over a specified amount of time (pauses in between each switch of color) based on a certain criteria (such as string = "a" or "b"). My problem is I can't seem to make the entire application wait for one change until it moves on to the next, so to the user it just looks like the color starts then is immediately the last color.

I've tried CountDownTimers (which just continue to execute while the other timer is running), handlers (postDelayed(null, 5000)), Thread.Sleeps etc.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

Set color on ImageView to red
sleep for 500ms

```
for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){  
    if(stringCompare = "a") {  
    Set color on ImageView to blue  
    sleep for 500ms }  
else if(stringCompare = "b") {  
    Set color on ImageView to blue  
    sleep for 1000ms  
  }  
Set color on ImageView to red  
sleep for 500ms  
}
```

I know that's kind of crazy, but I've tried all the above methods I could think of with no success on actually making the program wait, but not completely stopping it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your activity (make it an inner class):

```
private class ColorChanger extends Thread
{
    final ImageView imageView;
    public ColorChanger(ImageView imageView)
    {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    private void changeColor(final int color)
    {
        YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Set imageView to color here
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            changeColor(0xffff0000);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            changeColor(0xff0000ff);
            // Etc.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
new ColorChanger(/*Your imageview*/).start();
```

Anywhere in your activity.

Comment: Thanks monoceres, also very helpful!

Comment: I ended up going with this implementation. Everyone in this post helped me tremendously today and I think I have a 1000x better grasp on threads etc. now lol. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

For the past two decades, most GUIs have been based on event-driven models. Some, such as Android, use a single-threaded event-driven model. Your request to change a color does not take immediate effect; rather, it puts a message on a work queue, to be processed by the main application thread. That main application thread is also what is running your code, unless you specifically move that code to a background thread.

As a result, never sleep on the main application thread. Otherwise, that thread is tied up and cannot process any sort of GUI events, let alone your request to change the color.

`postDelayed()` (on `View` or `Handler`) will allow you to schedule code to be run in the future on the main application thread, after a delay, without tying up the main application thread during that delay.

Comment: Thank you this helps me understand the process much more!

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate thread that does your pause and run. From that thread post messages to the UI thread to change the color of its imageview.

Comment: Thanks, I am still learning so I will look further into threads. I've tried a Handler with a Runnable that updates the colors after the ms allowed but no success yet. If you or anyone else has any additional info that would help please post it too :) Thanks again

Comment: Here is what your should have. A handler in your activity. This handler should be able to receive messages based on which the color is changed. in your onPause create a new thread with a runnable that has a control statement with Thread.sleep(ms) and sendEmptyMessages to the UI thread with a code in 'what'. The handler manages the rest.